# react-native init freezes while installing react native in windows 10?

Tags: react-native

I have installed react-native-cli globally in my windows 10 as react native supports windows now.But when i init a new project it freezes while installing react native.

Comment: How long do you give it before deciding its frozen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react-native init process can be time consuming because it's quietly installing react-native and all its dependencies, which can take a few minutes.